# iOS View Based Application template: "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" where is viewController initialized?

Tags: ios, view, controller, viewcontroller

When you create a new xcode project using a view based application template, here is the code in the app delegate for the viewController in the "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In [Apple's Your First iOS Application Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/03_AddingViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH5-SW5)

which starts with the window based application template, we need to alloc and init our viewcontroller class and then point the app delegates viewcontroller ivar to that.  Then release.  See code below:

```
    MyViewController *aViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]
            initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self setMyViewController:aViewController];
[aViewController release];
```

I can't find memory allocation or initialization anywhere in the view-based application template.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The initialization is made in the NIB (named in the plist), doing it again in code would be useless, while the second example doesn't create in NIB and, therefore, needs an initialization in code... or maybe I'm missing something.